# save as pdf output appears really narrow and has many pages

Tags: pdf-format, save

If I attempt 'save as' pdf I sometimes (but not always) get really narrow output, resulting in many pages of output.

[image: big ugly page]

Notice how little text ends up on the page.  I can't see any settings that I've used explicitly that would result in the print font being so much bigger than the display font.

Comment: Probably something to do with print styles in your stylesheet. Got to Format > ScreenEnvironment > Printout to see what is going on and then make changes to the relevant styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(per Mike's comment).  In Mathematica 9, the save as pdf produces more reasonable results after selecting:

File -> Printing Settings -> Printing Environment -> Printout